# Json string convert to c# using newtonsoft

Tags: c#, json.net

I am facing difficulty converting json like below to List of class Note

```
[{"12":{"id":"12","cdate":"2018-05-16 00:32:53","note":"Some notes will go here...","first_name":"Mark","last_name":"1"}},
{"13":{"id":"13","cdate":"2018-05-16 00:32:53","note":"Some notes will go here...","first_name":"Mark","last_name":"1"}},
{"14":{"id":"14","cdate":"2018-05-16 00:32:53","note":"Some notes will go here...","first_name":"Mark","last_name":"1"}}]
```

I am using class like below

```
public class Notes{
 public int id {get; set;}
 public DateTime cdate {get; set;}
 public string note {get; set;}
 public string first_name {get; set;}
 public string last_name {get; set;}
}
```

---

Basically i am trying to convert all values in json specified above to list of class "Notes". I am facing trouble as it is having all different keys to it.

I have tried using below code

```
var rowJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(acDealInfo.deal_notes);

                            var oDealNotes =  JObject.Parse(rowJson);

                            var result = oDealNotes
                                .OfType<JProperty>()
                                .Select(p => new KeyValuePair<string, object>(p.Path,
                                    p.Value.Type == JTokenType.Array || p.Value.Type == JTokenType.Object
                                        ? null : p.Value));
```

Comment: Could you let us know what have you tried so far

Comment: What have you tried? What's the exact problem?

Comment: I have tried converting it JObject.Parse, then looping each jproperty for key value pair but no help.

Basically i am trying to convert all values in json to list of class. I am facing trouble as all keys are different.

Comment: @Hiren here's a spoon feed for you. Check out [quicktype.io](https://app.quicktype.io/?share=vD4Q0NLAlBCSdTqdi700).

Comment: Thanks @JohnEphraimTugado, it's great help.